# Laravel from localhost to server error

Tags: php, laravel, exception

My laravel 4 project was created on localhost. Now i am trying to put it on the server (shared hosting) but i am running in to an error. First let me explain how i uploaded my laravel project.

```
mydomain.nl

mydomain.nl--public_html
mydomain.nl--public_html--dev
mydomain.nl--public_html--packages
mydomain.nl--public_html--index.php
mydomain.nl--public_html--.htacces
mydomain.nl--public_html--all other contents form public laravel folders 

mydomain.nl--project
mydomain.nl--project--bootstrap
mydomain.nl--project--vendor
mydomain.nl--project--app
mydomain.nl--project--all other folders and files wich were not in laravel public folder
```

Then i changed my mydomain.nl/project/bootstrap/paths.php to:

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public_html',
```

And my mydomain.nl/public_html/index.php to

```
 require __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/autoload.php';
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/start.php';
```

If i go to my domain i get the following error

Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/hostingvariables/project/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: fopen(/hostingvariables/project/app/storage/logs/laravel.log) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /hostingvariables/project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:77

I tryd everyting i could imagine but i can not solve this error, if someone could help me solve this error that would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you dont have write access to

`/hostingvariables/project/app/storage/logs/laravel.log`

it says

> Permission denied

So if you can chmod it to 775, or contact your host if it a shared solution where they control write access

Comment: ah nice it only worked when i changed it to 777. are there any other files that need 777 or can i give everything in the project folder 777 right? it is not in my public_html folder

Comment: only give /storage folder (and it is subfolders) 777 access. No need for your whole project.

Comment: Thanks a ton i found http://laravel.com/docs/installation#configuration because of your answer i was looking for a way diffrent solution thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I like this method best. Instead of changing folder permissions, set Apache to run as you.

1. In terminal type `id` to get `uid=123(Myname)`.
2. Open /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and edit it to use your username.

   ```
   <IfModule unixd_module>
      User Myname
      Group staff
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. Back to terminal: `sudo apachectl restart`